# In Mac VI editor getting the `$p` character at the beginning of file

Tags: regex, macos, unix, vim

Recently something broken in my VI editor and whenever I open a file in VI editor it add/replace the begining character of file with `$p` character.

Its very annoying and I checked in `.viminfo` and `.vimrc` file and this character wasn't there. Below is the content of my `.vimrc` file

```
syntax on
set nobackup
set hidden
set hlsearch
set incsearch
if &diff
    "colorscheme desert
    highlight DiffAdd term=reverse cterm=bold ctermbg=green ctermfg=white
    highlight DiffChange term=reverse cterm=bold ctermbg=cyan ctermfg=black
    highlight DiffText term=reverse cterm=bold ctermbg=gray ctermfg=black
    highlight DiffDelete term=reverse cterm=bold ctermbg=red ctermfg=black
endif
set completeopt=longest,menuone
```

And below is the content of my `.viminfo` file.

`````
# You may edit it if you're careful!

# Viminfo version
|1,4

# Value of 'encoding' when this file was written
*encoding=utf-8


# hlsearch on (H) or off (h):
~h
# Last Search Pattern:
~MSle0~/$p

# Last Substitute Search Pattern:
~MSle0&pick

# Last Substitute String:
$````
`````

Comment: Does it happen if you open a file using `vim -u NONE`?

Also what plugins are you running and what setup are you using? (what OS, are you opening in terminal or macvim or whatever)

Comment: @StunBrick , no it doesn't happen when I opened a file, command given by you. I am using macos and It doesn't happen in terminal which comes with macOS , I am using `iTerm` and not using any plugin of it.